# android error with scheduling instance methods

Tags: android, timer, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, timertask

I am a new Android developer. I have a problem with scheduling.

I want to schedule one of my instance methods to be called with 1 second delay. I have tried Timer and TimerTask but it didn't work. It invoked the method but in method I am adding view to my relative layout. Gives error in there. without scheduling, if I invoke same method it doesnt fail.

So, what is the way to invoke a method with a delay without this kind of problems??
Or any way that I can wait for delay without pausing the thread, since it is my UIThread??

Comment: It seems like you want to do something similar to [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html "Updating the UI from a Timer"). Could you post the code you have tried and the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are getting?
If its because you update the UI not from the UI thread, then on your timer method user `Activity.runOnUiThread` method to run the code on the UI thread.

Or you can use `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>` and in its `doInBackground` sleep for a second, then use again the `Activity.runOnUiThread` to do whatever you need to do.